# React native listen to all events

Tags: javascript, mobile, react-native, event-listener

I am creating idle timer in my app and I want to reset timer on each click, scroll and etc. It seems a nonsense to call my `resetTimer()` function on every onPress event. In web I would do event listeners like: `$(document).mousemove()`, `$(document).mousedown()`, `$(document).scroll()` and etc.

Any suggestions on having some top-level event listeners that could call `resetTimer()` on any touch event in React native?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a day of investigating rect-native code I found **[fbjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fbjs)** that contains `TouchEventUtils` (facebook uses it in their react native tests), which allows to use different touch event state functions(`onTouchMove(event)`, `onTouchStart(event)`, `onTouchEnd(event)`).

So what I did:

```
npm install fbjs --save
```

And simply added `onTouchStart` to to my top level Root component that wrapps my routes, therefore I have all screens covered as I am using it on all screens/views wrapper.

So my code looks something like this:

```
/* rest of my imports */
import TouchEventUtils from 'fbjs/lib/TouchEventUtils';

class Root extends Component {

    onTouchStart(){
        //my code to properly reset session timer
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View
                onTouchStart={this.onTouchStart}
            >
                {/*My routes*/}
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

And thats it, that's the solution to accesing top level event listener and doing something on every event. I didn't dig deeper(as this was enough for my case), so I am not sure what object it gets and if it can help to identify any further properties(i.e. making logging of clicked elements).

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I needed for a screensaver feature.

Comment: Note that importing TouchEventUtils is not necessary.  onTouchStart is a built-in supported prop of the View component.

Comment: You are my savior!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an official API for this.

As a part of investigating how we could use [Cycle.js with React Native](https://github.com/cyclejs/cycle-react-native), we did experiment on monkey patching the `__fbBatchedBridge` global defined by the [BatchedBridge](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/BatchedBridge/BatchedBridge.js) module to listen to all global events coming in from the native side.

It was not suitable for us, because all we get are raw touch events, and it wasn't possible to filter for different kinds of event types. But if what you indeed want is to know when any touch event occurs, that solution might work for you.

It would, of course, be brittle and hacky :)

Comment: Nice to see you again(we've met @ Cycle.js conf)! :) Good suggestion, bit hacky as you say, but I think it is just enough I need. :)

Comment: Haha that is so funny, it was exactly at CycleConf where I developed this hack in the first place. Didn't recognize your name, though, just a pure coincidence :)